# How to rename file while uploading catalog images in Magento2

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, image-upload

When you upload a product image from backend to Magento that has the name that we are uploading like slide1.jpg I need to rename uploaded file name to productsku_slide1.jpg and same for other images.

In frontend when we save image as in gallery through any browser it should get downloaded with name productsku_slide1.jpg.
Can anyone please provide solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add your logic to `catalog_product_save_commit_after` event

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/events.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_commit_after">
        <observer name="acme_stackexchange_observer_product_save_commit_after_media"
                  instance="Acme\StackExchange\Observer\Catalog\NormalizeProductMedia"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

2. Observer to update image names and labels

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Observer/Catalog/NormalizeProductMedia.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Observer\Catalog;

use Acme\StackExchange\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Product\Gallery as GalleryResource;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config as MediaConfig;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityMetadata;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database as DatabaseStorage;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader as FileUploader;

class NormalizeProductMedia implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EntityMetadata|EntityMetadataInterface
     */
    protected $metadata;

    /**
     * @var MediaConfig
     */
    protected $mediaConfig;

    /**
     * @var GalleryResource
     */
    protected $galleryResource;

    /**
     * @var ProductAttributeInterface
     */
    protected $attribute;

    /**
     * @var WriteInterface
     */
    protected $mediaDirectory;

    /**
     * @var WriteInterface
     */
    protected $pubDirectory;

    /**
     * @var DatabaseStorage
     */
    protected $fileStorageDb;

    /**
     * @param MetadataPool $metadataPool
     * @param MediaConfig $mediaConfig
     * @param GalleryResource $galleryResource
     * @param ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param DatabaseStorage $fileStorageDb
     * @throws FileSystemException
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function __construct(
        MetadataPool $metadataPool,
        MediaConfig $mediaConfig,
        GalleryResource $galleryResource,
        ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        DatabaseStorage $fileStorageDb
    ) {
        $this->metadata        = $metadataPool
            ->getMetadata(ProductInterface::class);
        $this->mediaConfig     = $mediaConfig;
        $this->attribute       = $attributeRepository->get('media_gallery');
        $this->galleryResource = $galleryResource;
        $this->mediaDirectory  = $filesystem
            ->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->pubDirectory    = $filesystem
            ->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::PUB);
        $this->fileStorageDb   = $fileStorageDb;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer): void
    {
        /** @var Product $product */
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
        $images  = $this->galleryResource->loadProductGalleryByAttributeId(
            $product, $this->attribute->getAttributeId());

        if (!$images) {
            return;
        }
        foreach ($images as &$image) {
            if ($image['media_type'] !== 'image') {
                continue;
            }
            $this->updateImageLabel($product, $image);

            if (!$this->fileStorageDb->checkDbUsage()) {
                $this->updateImageFilename($product, $image);
            }
        }
        unset($image);
    }

    /**
     * @param Product $product
     * @param array $image
     */
    protected function updateImageLabel(Product $product, array &$image): void
    {
        $isNameChanged = $product->dataHasChangedFor('name');

        if ((string)$image['label'] !== '' && !$isNameChanged) {
            return;
        }
        if ($isNameChanged) {
            $oldName = $product->getOrigData('name');
            // keep custom label
            if (stripos((string)$image['label'], $oldName . ' - ') === false) {
                return;
            }
        }

        $image['label'] = sprintf('%s - %d',
            $product->getName(), $image['position'] + 1);

        $storeId   = (int)$product->getStoreId();
        $linkField = $this->metadata->getLinkField();
        $data      = [
            'value_id' => $image['value_id'],
            'label'    => $image['label'],
            'position' => isset($image['position']) ? (int)$image['position'] : 0,
            'disabled' => isset($image['disabled']) ? (int)$image['disabled'] : 0,
            'store_id' => $storeId,
            $linkField => (int)$product->getData($linkField),
        ];

        try {
            $this->galleryResource->updateGalleryValue($data);

            $hasLabel = ['image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'];
            $affected = $this->getAffectedMediaAttributes($product, $image);
            foreach ($affected as $attrCode) {
                if (in_array($attrCode, $hasLabel, true)) {
                    $product->setData($attrCode . '_label', $image['label']);
                    $product->addAttributeUpdate(
                        $attrCode . '_label',
                        $image['label'],
                        $storeId
                    );
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param Product $product
     * @param array $image
     */
    protected function updateImageFilename(
        Product $product,
        array &$image
    ): void {
        $file    = $image['file'];
        if (empty($file)) {
            return;
        }

        if (strpos($file, $product->getSku() . '_') !== false) {
            return;
        }

        $newFile = false;
        $oldFile = $file;
        if (!$this->mediaDirectory->isExist($this->mediaConfig->getMediaPath($oldFile))) {
            return;
        }

        $affected = $this->getAffectedMediaAttributes($product, $image);
        $fileExt  = strtolower(pathinfo($oldFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        $fileExt  = strtr($fileExt, ['jpeg' => 'jpg']);

        try {
            for ($i = 1; $i < 500; $i++) {
                $tmpName = sprintf('%s_slide%d.%s',
                    $product->getSku(), $i, $fileExt);
                $tmpPath = FileUploader::getDispersionPath($tmpName);
                $tmpFile = $this->mediaConfig->getMediaPath($tmpPath . '/' . $tmpName);

                if (!$this->mediaDirectory->isExist($tmpFile)) {
                    $newFile = $tmpPath . '/' . $tmpName;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!$newFile) {
                return;
            }

            $this->mediaDirectory->renameFile(
                $this->mediaConfig->getMediaPath($oldFile),
                $this->mediaConfig->getMediaPath($newFile)
            );

            $this->clearProductCache($newFile);

            $image['file'] = $newFile;

            $this->saveGalleryEntity($image);
            $this->saveAffectedAttributes($product, $affected, $newFile);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param Product $product
     * @param array $image
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getAffectedMediaAttributes(
        Product $product,
        array $image
    ): array {
        $file = $image['new_file'] ?? $image['file'];
        if (empty($file)) {
            return [];
        }

        $affected   = [];
        $attributes = $this->mediaConfig->getMediaAttributeCodes();
        foreach ($attributes as $attrCode) {
            if ($product->getData($attrCode) === $file) {
                $affected[] = $attrCode;
            }
        }

        return $affected;
    }

    /**
     * @param Product $product
     * @param array $affected
     * @param string $file
     */
    protected function saveAffectedAttributes(
        Product $product,
        array $affected,
        string $file
    ): void {
        foreach ($affected as $attrCode) {
            $product->setData($attrCode, $file);
            $product->addAttributeUpdate(
                $attrCode,
                $file,
                (int)$product->getStoreId()
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param array $image
     */
    protected function saveGalleryEntity(array $image): void
    {
        $data = [
            'value_id'     => $image['value_id'],
            'attribute_id' => (int)$this->attribute->getAttributeId(),
            'value'        => $image['file'],
            'media_type'   => $image['media_type'],
            'disabled'     => $image['disabled'] ?? 0,
        ];

        $this->galleryResource->saveDataRow(
            $this->galleryResource::GALLERY_TABLE,
            $data,
            ['value']
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param string $file
     */
    protected function clearProductCache(string $file): void
    {
        try {
            $pattern = sprintf('cache/*/%s', ltrim($file, '/'));
            $path    = $this->mediaConfig->getBaseMediaPath();
            $result  = $this->mediaDirectory->search($pattern, $path);
            foreach ($result as $cacheFile) {
                $this->mediaDirectory->delete($cacheFile);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
    }
}
```

3. Some extend to Gallery Resource

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Model/ResourceModel/Catalog/Product/Gallery.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Product;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Gallery extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Gallery
{
    public function updateGalleryValue(array $data)
    {
        $connection = $this->getConnection();
        $linkField  = $this->metadata->getLinkField();

        if (!isset($data['value_id'], $data[$linkField], $data['store_id'])) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Missed required fields for Media Gallery Value'));
        }
        unset($data['record_id']);

        $data = $this->_prepareDataForTable(
            new DataObject($data),
            $this->getTable(self::GALLERY_VALUE_TABLE)
        );

        $select = $connection->select()
            ->from($this->getTable(self::GALLERY_VALUE_TABLE), 'record_id')
            ->where('value_id = ?', (int)$data['value_id'])
            ->where($linkField . ' = ?', (int)$data[$linkField])
            ->where('store_id = ?', (int)$data['store_id']);
        $recordId = $connection->fetchOne($select);

        if ($recordId !== false) {
            $connection->update(
                $this->getTable(self::GALLERY_VALUE_TABLE),
                $data,
                $connection->quoteInto('record_id = ?', (int)$recordId)
            );
        } else {
            $connection->insert(
                $this->getTable(self::GALLERY_VALUE_TABLE),
                $data
            );
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Feel free to update a logic inside according to you requirements